# What is the expression for the set of all nonduplicate subsets for k-many elements?

Tags: combinatorics

For k-many elements, is the power set, ℘, 2^k? If so, it would seem that the power set would included ordered pairs that, if unordered, would be duplicates (e.g., {3,1}; {1,3}. What then would be the expression that would be the power set of non-duplicate unordered pairs, including the empty set? So, for example, let's say we have 3-many elements {x, y, and z}. The power set then would be {∅, x, y, z, xy, xz, yx, yz, zx, zy}. But, what is the expression that provides the following proper subset of the power set: {∅, x, y, z, xy, xz, yz}.

Comment: As Banana says below, sets do *not* have order. The power set does not contain any duplicates. Notice how the correct (second) power set you wrote down has exactly 2^3 elements, just as the formula predicts.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! What then is the equation for all of the ordered sets that can be derived from k-many elements if we do not obey the principle of extensionality?

Comment: The number of ways to pick $r$ elements out of $k$ is $\binom{k}{r}$. The number of linear orderings on $r$ elements is $r!$. Therefore the number of linear orders on subsets of $\{1,\cdots,k\}$ is given by $\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{k}{r}r!$.

Comment: What does *"an example of how to derive the number of ordered pairs using this equation"* mean? I already gave you a derivation, it's strange to ask for "an example of how to prove X," and you would not use the equation to prove the equation. Did you mean **calculate** the number using the formula? You just plug the values into the formula! Do you not know how summation notation works? Why are you multiplying $k\times k$ and adding $1$? What does that even have to do with counting linear orders on subsets? Why would you think it works?

Comment: It's easily seen that $2^k=\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{k}{r}\le\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{k}{r}r!$ holds, with equality if and only if $r!=1$ for all $0\le r\le k$ which holds if and only if $k$ is $0$ or $1$. Of course $k\ge r$, the number $r$ is a dummy variable that by design ranges from $0$ to $k$, it's not like it's a constant or an independent parameter. That's how summation notation works.

Comment: Figured out my mistake! Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sets do not have order. the set $\{1,2,3\}$ is the same as the set $\{2,3,1\}$ if we have a set with $n$ elements then that set has $2^n$ subsets, this formula doesn't count duplicates.

This formula can be obtained by seeing if we were to construct a subset ourselves,for every element we would have the option of including it or not including it (2 options). And we would have to make this decision $n$ times, therefore the number of subsets would be $\underbrace{2\cdot2\dots \cdot2} _\text{n times}=2^n$